# Regex match domain name without www and keep website.com still intact

Tags: regex

I have this regex

```
^(?:http(?:s)?://)?(?:www(?:[0-9]+)?\.)
```

to strip off the www and http(s):// part of any domain name and give just the domain name. It works with:

- example.com
- http://example.com
- http://www.example.com

But when used with a domain name starting with letter w it strips the w off

- website.com => ebsite.com

Any ideas on how to make it better? Please test it with this data set  http://regexr.com/3abl2

Thanks

Comment: `(?:s)?` can be written more simply as `s?`

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like this:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*)$
```

Please [see this Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oU0iQ2/1) for examples and explanation.

**UPDATE** It looks like you also want to omit `www0`, `www1`, etc.? Then you'll want this:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www[0-9]*\.)?(.*)$
```

[Please see updated demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/oU0iQ2/2)

Answer (score 0):

- Drop the part `(?:[0-9]+)?.)` from the regex
- Add optional quantifier `?` to `www`. Matches zero or one `www`

The regex can be written as

```
^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www)?
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://www.regex101.com/r/jW1uY3/2)

Comment: There is no `www` or `http` in `example.com` to drop them off

Comment: I'm using the expression in php which also has the same issue at regexr.com/3abl2 : skips `http://example.com`